# Why does IE8 sometimes not load anything in a new tab? 

Tags: internet-explorer

Sometimes when I click a link on web page and open it in new tab, the web page will never be loaded.

But if I copy the URL and paste it to address bar to open it in new tab, everything is OK.

I googled a while and find a lot complain about this. I can't beleive such a big bug could survive for such a long time.

Have you ever met that before? What might cause the problem?

Comment: I can't believe the "bug" of not supporting CSS standards has survived for such a long time either. You come to expect issues with MSIE after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that problem and thats why i switched over to [firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/personal.html). I never use IE. The problem is simply caused by the programming and development of IE8. You can really only wait and hope that a patch or new version comes out to fix the issue.